# Asistance with KQL under log analytics workspace

Tags: azure-log-analytics

```
ConfigurationChange
| where ConfigChangeType == "WindowsServices"
and SvcState == "Stopped"
and (
Computer has "NET-SQL2.networkhg.org.uk"
or Computer has "NET-SQL3.networkhg.org.uk"
or Computer has "NET-GISSQL1.networkhg.org.uk"
or Computer has "NET-CALSQL.networkhg.org.uk"
)
and (
SvcDisplayName == "SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (TEST)"
or SvcDisplayName == "SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (MSSQLSERVER)"
or SvcDisplayName == "SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (SQLEXPRESS)"
or SvcDisplayName == " SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)"
or SvcDisplayName == "SQL Server (Test) "
or SvcDisplayName == "SQL Server Agent (MSSQLSERVER)"
or SvcDisplayName == "SQL Server Agent (Test)"
or SvcDisplayName == "SQL Server Browser"
or SvcDisplayName == "SQL Server Integration Services 10.0"
or SvcDisplayName == "SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (FIDO)"
or SvcDisplayName == "SQL Full-text Filter Daemon Launcher (SUN)"
or SvcDisplayName == "SQL Server (FIDO)"
or SvcDisplayName == "SQL Server (SUN)"
or SvcDisplayName == "SQL Server Agent (FIDO)"
or SvcDisplayName == "SQL Server VSS Writer"
or SvcDisplayName == " SQL Server Integration Services 11.0"
or SvcDisplayName == "SQL Server Reporting Services (MSSQLSERVER)"
or SvcDisplayName == "SQL Server Reporting Services (SQLEXPRESS)"
or SvcDisplayName == "SQL Server Analysis Services (MSSQLSERVER)"
)
```

Question to ask, if one of the service gets stopped in any of the server mentioned above, will I get an email with regards to that server or all the servers will be listed

Answer (score 0):

Writing the query is only half of your question. An alert based off this query [will need to be created](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-log) to get an email.

The email would be the result of the query which in this case would be all the combinations of servers/services that are stopped.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, I  have got the answer to this question, I have created another query similar to this, and I created an alert to email to action a group, if any service gets stopped in the combination of servers.

Insights
Top 10 result(s)
Computer    NH-P2PAPP01.networkhg.org.uk

ConfigChangeType    WindowsServices
ChangeCategory  Modified
SourceComputerId    d901f954-1d9a-43b5-a0b9-afd0cf688923
SvcChangeType   State
SvcDisplayName  Integra SPC FINPROD
SvcName SPCFINPROD
SvcState    Stopped
SvcPreviousState    Running
SvcStartupType  Auto
SvcAccount  LocalSystem
SvcPath F:\Integra\intspc\FINPROD\bin..\bin\spc_64.exe //RS//SPCFINPROD
SourceSystem    OpsManager
MG  00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001
ManagementGroupName AOI-4d3a9999-1d9a-4086-8d0c-1a31ac03c9d8
TenantId    4d3a9999-1d9a-4086-8d0c-1a31ac03c9d8
TimeGenerated   2020-06-14T01:00:20
VMUUID  116e3f42-eb84-de2e-00c5-c56ed4f4b80f
LastSnapshotAge 60
Type    ConfigurationChange